# pandas column selection using boolean values from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a 1*20000 columns dataframe of boolean values.
I need these boolean values to select a dataframe (551 rows* 20000 columns) columns.

```
   [In]  web.shape
   [Out] (550, 20000)
   [In]  language.shape
   [Out] (1, 20000)
   [In]  language
   [Out] Index(['zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh',
   ...'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na'],
       dtype='object', name='Page', length=20000)
```

Now I'd like to take out those columns of **web** where language is **chinese**('zn')i.e., where the **column positions** of language are **TRUE**.I need those columns as **seperate data frame**. The column names are different for web and language.

```
   [In] language=pd.DataFrame(language)

   [In] English =web.iloc[:,language=='zn']
   [Out] ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

I know the error was caused by the indexes of the language dataframe. but I am thinking there must be some good solution to avoid it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @greg_data added description and code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simplified example, so I can show the process here.

```
language = pd.Index(['zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh', 'zh','zh','na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na'],
   dtype='object', name='Page')

web = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(len(language)))

web.shape
(0, 20)

language.shape
(0, 20)
```

So both have the same number of columns, and you want to filter `web` down to only those columns where the equivalent entry in `language` is `'zh'`.

When I run your code:

```
English = web.iloc[:,language=='zh']
```

It doesn't return an error, it returns what you are after. This leads me to believe there is some code we aren't seeing here in your description.

Another solution to what you want would be:

```
English = web[[i for  i,j in zip(web.columns, language) if j == 'zh']]
```

which will also return only those columns in web where the equivalent in language is equal to a desired value.